# Nothing comes up when I type this in python

Tags: python

I really need to know why nothing comes up on python when I type this code.

Is this because of the `def myscript()`?

I am new to both Python and this website - Stackoverflow.

```
import time
def myscript():
    print("What do you want to buy? You have currently")
    print ("You have a choice between the following and may only buy one:")
    time.sleep(1)    
    pistol = 20
    print("A pistol for 20 coins")
    time.sleep(1)
    costfuel = 10
    print("15 fuel for 10 coins")
    time.sleep(1)
    shotgun = 40
    print("A shotgun for 40 coins")
    time.sleep(1)
    costoxygen = 10
    print("10 oxygen for 10 coins")
    time.sleep(1)
    costlife = 50
    print("or 5 life for 50 coins")
    time.sleep(1)
    choose = input("You may now choose which of the following you want - please type it in e.g pistol. ")
    if choose == "pistol":
        while Coins < pistol:
             print ("You cannot buy this as you do not have enough money.")
             time.sleep(4)
             myscript()
        else:
             print ("Thank you for purchasing the pistol! You have",Coins,"coins remaining")
    elif choose == "costfuel":
        while Coins < costfuel:
             print ("You cannot buy this as you do not have enough money.")
             time.sleep(4)
             myscript()
        else:
            print ("Thank you for purchasing the fuel! You have",Fuel,"fuel remaining and",Coins,"coins remaining.")
    else:
        while Coins < shotgun:
            print ("You cannot buy this as you do not have enough money.")
            time.sleep(4)
            myscript()
        else:
            print ("Thank you for purchasing the shotgun! You have",Coins,"coins remaining")
    myscript()
```

Comment: de-indint the last line by four spaces/

Comment: Are you sure the myscript() at the bottom is tabbed right. I think it is part of your function definition.

Comment: The indentation in your example is not fine. Please correct it. Do you get any error messages, when you execute the code? Where does the variable "Coins" come from? I don't see where did you declare it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FirebladeDan What's the point with `Coins` and `Fuel`? Maybe they are global variables, but how should I exactly know. The OP should provide the relevant code.

Comment: should i just send all my coding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

myscript() is tabbed wrong, it is part of your function definition. import time also looks off.

Here is the corrected code. Do you see the difference?

```
import time    
def myscript():
    print("What do you want to buy? You have currently")
    print ("You have a choice between the following and may only buy one:")
    time.sleep(1)    
    pistol = 20
    print("A pistol for 20 coins")
    time.sleep(1)
    costfuel = 10
    print("15 fuel for 10 coins")
    time.sleep(1)
    shotgun = 40
    print("A shotgun for 40 coins")
    time.sleep(1)
    costoxygen = 10
    print("10 oxygen for 10 coins")
    time.sleep(1)
    costlife = 50
    print("or 5 life for 50 coins")
    time.sleep(1)
    choose = input("You may now choose which of the following you want - please type it in e.g pistol. ")
    if choose == "pistol":
        while Coins < pistol:
             print ("You cannot buy this as you do not have enough money.")
             time.sleep(4)
             myscript()
        else:
             print ("Thank you for purchasing the pistol! You have",Coins,"coins remaining")
    elif choose == "costfuel":
        while Coins < costfuel:
             print ("You cannot buy this as you do not have enough money.")
             time.sleep(4)
             myscript()
        else:
            print ("Thank you for purchasing the fuel! You have",Fuel,"fuel remaining and",Coins,"coins remaining.")
    else:
        while Coins < shotgun:
            print ("You cannot buy this as you do not have enough money.")
            time.sleep(4)
            myscript()
        else:
            print ("Thank you for purchasing the shotgun! You have",Coins,"coins remaining")
myscript()
```

Comment: im not sure what you mean

Comment: Then you should take a look at the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial).

Comment: Python uses indentation, myscript() calls the function that your code is in. But it is indented so that it is part of your function. Thus it is never getting called. Also if your function did get called it would recursively call itself.

Comment: basically when i run it it just shows nothing not even syntax error or anything

Comment: Remove 4 spaces from the front of myscript() basically.

Comment: i have added coins fuel and everything this is only part of my code

Comment: I have ran it and it does work, I have provided the code to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
import time    
    def myscript():
        print("What do you want to buy? You have currently")
        print ("You have a choice between the following and may only buy one:")
        time.sleep(1) 
        ...
```

write:

```
import time    
def myscript():
    print("What do you want to buy? You have currently")
    print ("You have a choice between the following and may only buy one:")
    time.sleep(1) 
    ...
```

then call it

```
myscript()
```

You're facing an **indentation** problem.

Comment: oh i have already tried that but for some reason it says myscript() is not defined